# How to store url contents in variable and upload to Amazon S3?

Tags: php, video, amazon-web-services

So, I've been trying to get this to work for the past couple hours, but I can't figure it out. The goal is to pull the converted mp4 file from gfycat and upload that file to the Amazon S3 bucket.

gfycat is returning a JSON object properly, and $result->mp4Url is returning a correct url to the mp4 file. I keep getting errors such as "object expected, string given". Any ideas? Thanks.

```
// convert the gif to video format using gfycat
$response = file_get_contents("http://upload.gfycat.com/transcode/" . $key . 
     "?fetchUrl=" . urlencode($upload->getUrl('g')));
$result = json_decode($response);
$result_mp4 = file_get_contents($result->mp4Url);

// save the converted file to AWS S3 /i
$s3->putObject(array(
     'Bucket'     => getenv('S3_BUCKET'),
     'Key'        => 'i/' . $upload->id64 . '.mp4',
     'SourceFile' => $result_mp4,
));
```

var_dump($response) yields:

```
string '{
    "gfyId":"vigorousspeedyinexpectatumpleco",
    "gfyName":"VigorousSpeedyInexpectatumpleco",
    "gfyNumber":"884853904",
    "userName":"anonymous",
    "width":250,
    "height":250,
    "frameRate":11,
    "numFrames":67,
    "mp4Url":"http:\/\/zippy.gfycat.com\/VigorousSpeedyInexpectatumpleco.mp4",
    "webmUrl":"http:\/\/zippy.gfycat.com\/VigorousSpeedyInexpectatumpleco.webm",
    "gifUrl":"http:\/\/fat.gfycat.com\/VigorousSpeedyInexpectatumpleco.gif",
    "gifSize":1364050,
    "mp4Size":240833,
    "webmSize":220389,
    "createDate":"1388777040",
    "views":"205",
    "title":'... (length=851)
```

Using json_decode() on it also yields similar results.

Comment: What does `var_dump($response);` show? And error occurs on which line?

Comment: Edited original post with var_dump() results, and the error occurs on the 'SourceFile' => $result_mp4; line.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up the `'SourceFile'` parameter (which accepts a file path) with the `'Body'` parameter (which accepts raw data). See [Uploading Objects](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-s3.html#uploading-objects) in the AWS SDK for PHP User Guide for more examples.

Here are 2 options that should work:

#### Option 1 (Using SourceFile)

```
// convert the gif to video format using gfycat
$response = file_get_contents("http://upload.gfycat.com/transcode/" . $key . 
     "?fetchUrl=" . urlencode($upload->getUrl('g')));
$result = json_decode($response);

// save the converted file to AWS S3 /i
$s3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'     => getenv('S3_BUCKET'),
    'Key'        => 'i/' . $upload->id64 . '.mp4',
    'SourceFile' => $result->mp4Url,
));
```

#### Option 2 (Using Body)

```
// convert the gif to video format using gfycat
$response = file_get_contents("http://upload.gfycat.com/transcode/" . $key . 
     "?fetchUrl=" . urlencode($upload->getUrl('g')));
$result = json_decode($response);
$result_mp4 = file_get_contents($result->mp4Url);

// save the converted file to AWS S3 /i
$s3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'  => getenv('S3_BUCKET'),
    'Key'    => 'i/' . $upload->id64 . '.mp4',
    'Body'   => $result_mp4,
));
```

Option 1 is better though, because the SDK will use a file handle to mp4 file instead of loading the entire thing into memory (like file_get_contents does).